# how can i add HTML codes to my sharepoint site?

Tags: html-editor

I got a website. I want to change object's alignments ,margin and padding. I am clicking "Edit page". Then , i am clicking which web part i want to change and "Edit source "on the top. It pops-up HTML editor. I am changing code. Then clicking Ok. It is normal for now. When i press "Save", all the changes is going.

Comment: I would advise using Internet Explorer for editing code snippets, as I have found that using Google Chrome can result in the text disappearing once you have saved the changes

Comment: you say use F12 ?

Comment: No, when editing webparts via the GUI, use Internet Explorer rather than Google Chrome.

Comment: Internet Explorer are not used widely as compared to chrome/mozilla/edge within an organisation. Better try editing fixing responsive in chrome only

Answer (score 4):

To add HTML code snippet in a page we can make use of **Script Editor** or **Content Editor** Web Part

[image]

Prefer Script Editor as its easy to handle the html code snippet here , Content Editor Web Part may some time misbehave.